# Qt window resize aspect ratio 1:1

Tags: qt, resize, window

I want to resize the app window proportionally 1:1. I tried to change it inside the ResizeEvent, but then I got the window flickering. Now my code looks like this, but it doesn't work.

filterobject.h:

```
class FilterObject:public QObject{
public:
    QWidget *target = nullptr;//it holds a pointer to target object
    int goalHeight=0;
    FilterObject(QObject *parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){}//uses QObject constructor
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;//and overrides eventFilter function
};
```

widget.h:

```
namespace Ui {
class Widget;

}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual int heightForWidth ( int w ) const { return w*9/16;}
    //virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

widget.cpp:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
   FilterObject *filter = new FilterObject();
   QWidget *targetWidget = new QWidget();
   filter->target=targetWidget;
   targetWidget->installEventFilter(filter);
}

bool FilterObject::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) {
    if(watched != target){//checks for correct target object.
        return false;
    }

    if(event->type() != QEvent::Resize){//and correct event
       return false;
    }

    QResizeEvent *resEvent = static_cast<QResizeEvent*>(event);

    goalHeight = 9*resEvent->size().width()/16;
    if(target->height()!=goalHeight){
        target->setFixedHeight(goalHeight);
    }

    return true;
};
```

Perhaps this code will work, but my condition if(event->type() != QEvent::Resize) does not work .. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code. First of all you should install event filter once e.g in your constructor. You create an object of event filter and install it every time `resizeEvent` is triggered which is wrong. Also you are installing event filter on the wrong object (a new `QWidget`). So remove the `resizeEvent` function and insert in the constructor of `Widget`:

```
FilterObject *filter = new FilterObject();
filter->target=this;
installEventFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, did as you said, now it works. But if i increase the window size, everything works with proportions, but if you decrease it, the resize is blocked and the window size can no longer be changed until the program is restarted.